# Running multiple compilations in Emacs (on Windows)?

Tags: emacs, elisp, compilation

[The GNU Emacs Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation.html) says:

> If you want to run two compilations at once, you should start the first one, then rename the ‘`*compilation*`’ buffer (perhaps using `rename-uniquely`; see [Misc Buffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Misc-Buffer.html#Misc-Buffer)), and start the other compilation. That will create a new ‘`*compilation*`’ buffer.

I tried this, but it didn't work as advertised. I'm running this [version](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Version-Info):

```
 GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2010-05-08 on G41R2F1
```

That is, [Emacs for Windows](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/), which might be the problem. Perhaps multiple compilations work well on other platforms?

**How do I run more than one compilation in Emacs?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Emacs manual is out of date, I'm afraid. If you <kbd>C-h f compile RET</kbd> you'll see this:

> To run more than one compilation at once, start one then rename the `*compilation*` buffer to some other name with `M-x rename-buffer`.  Then **switch buffers** and start the new compilation.
>   It will create a new `*compilation*` buffer.

Note the highlighted text.

I [filed a bug report](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=7573). (But really this is a common enough operation that there ought to be a command for it.)

Edited to add: now fixed! (Expect the fix to appear in Emacs 24.)

Comment: I can't see one. It should be easy enough to write your own, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little function to rename your compilation buffer to something unique:

```
(defun my-make-room-for-new-compilation-buffer ()
  "Renames existing *compilation* buffer to something unique so
      that a new compilation job can be run."
  (interactive)
  (let ((cbuf (get-buffer "*compilation*"))
        (more-cbufs t)
        (n 1)
        (new-cbuf-name ""))
    (when cbuf
      (while more-cbufs
        (setq new-cbuf-name (format "*compilation%d*" n))
        (setq n (1+ n))
        (setq more-cbufs (get-buffer new-cbuf-name)))
      (with-current-buffer cbuf
        (rename-buffer new-cbuf-name)))))
```

I'm sure there's lots of cleanup that could be done here, but it's a start...

Comment: Thanks for this code -- a good alternative until an Emacs 24 upgrade!

Comment: @GregMattes actually I don't think there is a new command in Emacs 24... So I think a homegrown solution is it :)

Answer (score 1):

Just go to *compilation* and call rename-uniquely.